# Can't apply .addClass to dynamically created element

Tags: jquery, addclass

I'm trying to apply .addClass to the the last item in an unordered list. The problem is, the unordered list is dynamically created from an external script. So I guess you can say, the script isn't really there until the external script constructs it. The script seems to load this in after the page and DOM is ready.

I've tried the old basics, but to no avail:

```
$(function() {
    $("#svpply_items li:last-child").addClass('last');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#svpply_items li:last-child").addClass('last');
});
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: can you attach a live load event/delegate one and change it in that?

Comment: Is there a callback function or event or anything from your external script that says "hey I am done"?

Comment: [http://api.jquery.com/live/](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: +1 Joseph, try to modify the script that loads that stuff to trigger a custom event, event to which you will bind that .addClass

Comment: That's for events, you can't use it to add a class.

Comment: I wish - Can't modify the external script as it's coming from svpply.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say make sure that all the scripts are at the bottom of you page and make sure that the ordering of external scripts is correct.  If that's already the case or you've already tried that to no avail, then take a look at the [$.getScript(...)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) function.

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getScript('scripts/external.js', function (data, textStatus) {
        $("#svpply_items li:last-child").addClass('last');
    });
});
```

Comment: This one here won't allow the script to load.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try it on `$(window).load(function(){....` ?

Comment: Nothing doing there - seems to still load it before the script loads itself. Can't modify the external script as it's coming from http://www.svpply.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#svpply_items").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
     $(this).find('li:last-child').addClass('last');
});
```

Comment: $("#svpply_items") won't select anything, that's the problem in the first place. Maybe putting it on the body ?

Comment: This is not advised as it is very resource heavy and not cross browser.

Comment: More importantly (and to my present dismay :\ ) .addClass triggers DOMSubtreeModified... I think the rest can be easily derived.